# override config file from helm chart with terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, argocd

I'm trying to deploy ArgoCD in my k8s cluser using the helm chart for ArgoCD. I deploy everything with Terraform. Now i want to change the config file from ArgoCD such that it can connect to my private repo. It works when i manually change the file using kubectl after ArgoCD is running in my cluster but when I try to use terraform, I get the message `Error: configmaps "argocd-cm" already exists` meaning that i cannot overrite the configmap that is created by ArgoCD. How to i change these variables?

terraform

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "argocd" {
  metadata {
    name = "argocd"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "argocd_registry_secret" {
  metadata {
    name = "argocd-repo-credentials"
    namespace = "argocd"
  }

  data = {
    username = "USERNAME"
    password = "PASSWORD"
  }
}

data "helm_repository" "argoproj" {
  name = "argoproj"
  url  = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
}

resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name       = "argocd"
  chart      = "argoproj/argo-cd"
  version    = "2.3.5"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.argocd.metadata[0].name
  timeout    = 600
}

resource "kubernetes_config_map"  "argocd-cm" {
  depends_on = [helm_release.argocd]
  metadata {
    name = "argocd-cm"
    namespace = "argocd"
  }

  data = {
    config =  file("${path.module}/configs/ingress/argo-configmap.yaml") 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `name` use `generate_name` in `kubernetes_config_map`

> generate_name - (Optional) Prefix, used by the server, to generate a unique name ONLY IF the name field has not been provided. This value will also be combined with a unique suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You can add private repo through argocd helm chart, add this to argocd helm release resource in TF file:

```
set {
  name = "server.config.repositories"
  value = "${file("${path.module}/repositories.yml")}"
}
```

where repositories.yml is:

```
- url: ssh://abc@def.com/my-repo.git
  sshPrivateKeySecret:         
    name: argo-cd-stash-key    
    key: ssh-privatekey
```