# How do I add users to Argo CD using terraform resource?

Tags: authentication, terraform, argocd

I've deployed ArgoCD using the following terraform, which uses the `argoproj` help chart.

```
resource "helm_release" "argo_cd" {
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  repository = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  name       = "argocd"
  namespace  = var.namespace
}
```

I knew when I created this that I needed to do two things.  I needed to:

1. Add API access to the default `admin` user
2. Add new users

It appears that the solution to both #1 and #2 are to edit the `configmap` deployed with the helm chart.  I've seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634665/override-config-file-from-helm-chart-with-terraform) about this very thing, but I've tried setting

I did try adding a `kubernetes_config_map` like the following to add a new local user (I didn't see how to add api_key access to the default admin account yet):

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "local_users" {
  metadata {
    #Also tried generate_name here
    name      = "argocd-cm"
    namespace = "argocd"

    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "argocd-cm"

      "app.kubernetes.io/part-of" = "argocd"
    }
  }

  data = {
    "accounts.new-user" = "apiKey, login"

    "accounts.new-user.enabled" = "true"
  }
}
```

When I deployed this, it said the `configmap` named `argocd-cm` already exists.  Which makes sense.  So, as seen from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634665/override-config-file-from-helm-chart-with-terraform) posted above, I tried setting to `generate_name`, which went through, but I don't see the new user.  And I can't query the API list names using `argocd account list`, because my default `admin` user doesn't have API access.

So, I need to know how to edit the existing `configmap` in terraform in order to add new users (assuming that is in fact the best method), and grant permission of the default `admin` user in order to use the API as that user.  Any help is hugely appreciated.

Also from the question above, I did try using the `set` values, but I'm fairly certain I'm formatting them incorrectly, or this isn't how you do it (shown below):

```
resource "helm_release" "argo_cd" {
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  repository = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  name       = "argocd"
  namespace  = var.namespace
  set {
    name = "accounts.new-user"
    value = "apiKey, login"
  }
}
```

Which just gives me a parsing error `failed parsing key "accounts.new-user" with value apiKey, login, key " login" has no value`

The current configmap named `argocd-cm` looks like this:

`kubectl get configmap argocd-cm -n argocd -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  exec.enabled: "false"
  server.rbac.log.enforce.enable: "false"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: argocd
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: argocd
  creationTimestamp: "2022-07-02T14:06:49Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
    helm.sh/chart: argo-cd-4.9.7
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
  resourceVersion: "4382002"
  uid: da102b9c-45d9-41j8-9c9a-f8cbca79b003
```

Comment: any thoughts on initializing argo-cd (via tf or bash or `<insert_tool>`) then letting argo manage itself declaratively - https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "argocd-cm" {
  force = true
  metadata {
    name      = "argocd-cm"
    namespace = "argocd-ns"
  }
  data = {
    "accounts.support"           = "login"
    "accounts.support.enabled"   = "true"
      
  }
}
```

This will update the existing configmaps and add the required users.

When we use  resource `kubernetes_config_map` - this resource will try to create new configmaps.